# Possible to force a migration from the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I made a rookie mistake with a migration yesterday. I amended a migration that had already been uploaded and run, and I forgot to rollback before uploading the new version. Now, the migration is failing because either a column already exists (up) or there is no column to delete (down)!

Is it possible to get a migration to force its changes one time from the console, **without** having to write `:force => true` within the document first, migrating, and then removing it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way of getting back to a stable state would be to make a manual change in the database adding the column so that the rollback works, and then do the rollback and migrate up again.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I'm using Heroku and I don't know of a way to access the db directly. It may just be easier to do a couple of uploads with the old migration/rollback + new migration/migrate up.

Comment: What if you do "heroku rake db:reset" in the command-line? It will erase all production data, yes, but will force all migrations, and you can restore the user data afterwards from a backup.